# Parsing a Content-Type header in Java without validating the charset

Tags: java, mime-types

Given an HTTP header like:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=something
```

I'd like to extract the MIME type and charset using full RFC-compliant parsing, but without "validating" the charset. By validating, I mean that I don't want to use Java's internal Charset mechanism, in case the charset is unknown to Java (but may still have meaning for other applications). The following code does not work because it does this validation:

```
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;

String header = "text/plain; charset=something";

ContentType contentType = ContentType.parse(header);
Charset contentTypeCharset = contentType.getCharset();

System.out.println(contentType.getMimeType());
System.out.println(contentTypeCharset == null ? null : contentTypeCharset.toString());
```

This throws `java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: something`.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively one can still use the [Apache's parse](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/ContentType.html#parse(java.lang.String)) and catch the `UnsupportedCharsetException` for extracting the name using [getCharsetName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/UnsupportedCharsetException.html#getCharsetName--:)

```java
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;

String header = "text/plain; charset=something";

String charsetName;
String mimeType;

try {
  ContentType contentType = ContentType.parse(header); // here exception may be thrown
   mimeType = contentType.getMimeType();
   Charset charset = contentType.getCharset();
   charsetName = charset != null ? charset.name() : null;
} catch( UnsupportedCharsetException e) {
    charsetName = e.getCharsetName(); // extract unsupported charsetName
    mimeType = header.substring(0, header.indexOf(';')); // in case of exception, mimeType needs to be parsed separately
}
```

Drawback is that `mimeType` also needs to be extracted differently in case of UnsupportedCharsetException.

Comment: I view the `header.substring(...)` part as a form of "manual parsing" of the header. If one does that one might as well extract the charset manually too. In the original question I wanted to use a proven, tested library to do that instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: The solution is covering frequent use-cases of header `Content-Type` with _standard library_ and its top-level functions. Just (rare) exceptions are caught by fallback to _manual_ parsing.

Answer (score 1):

To do the parsing one can use lower-level parsing classes:

```
import org.apache.http.HeaderElement;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueParser;

String header = "text/plain; charset=something";

HeaderElement headerElement = BasicHeaderValueParser.parseHeaderElement(header, null);
String mimeType = headerElement.getName();
String charset = null;
for (NameValuePair param : headerElement.getParameters()) {
    if (param.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("charset")) {
        String s = param.getValue();
        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(s)) {
            charset = s;
        }
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println(mimeType);
System.out.println(charset);
```